# Entourage Reminders for events not on calendar

Tags: macos, calendar, entourage

After a series of nasty mishaps, I needed to create a new Entourage profile and re-populate my calendar by resynching it with my Exchange Server.

Now I'm receiving multiple notifications for a single appointment -- two or even four at once. (Perhaps four is due to the intermediate 'reset' attempts I made before discarding and creating a new profile.)

Reviewing my calendar I see only a single appointment, not multiple appointments. Checking my Outlook calendar confirms only a single appointment. My local calendar is completely empty.

Is there a separate Entourage database for reminders that I can clear or resync? Is there somewhere else for calendar appointments to live where I'm not looking?

Comment: Give up on Entourage and switch to iCal in Snow Leopard. I did and nuked my Entourage profile. I know I'm not answering your question, but this is a realistic work around. Entourage is lousy software.

Comment: Not an option: Snow Leopard's Exchange integration requires Exchange 2007, whereas my work is still on Exchange 2003. Convincing my IT department to upgrade isn't really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These appointments are contained in the Entourage database. There appear to be no tools to modify this database to permit removing these appointments. Repairing the database has no impact.

Recommended approach appears to be creating a new profile and migrating all mail to that new profile. (Ugh.)